# Deploying a Symfony 2 project in a server

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I have trying to deploy a symfony 2 project into an online server but it does not work :(
This is the error log:

> ErrorException: Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the
>   allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/mySite.com/htdocs/:/var/www/mySite.com/phptmp/:/var/www/hra-performance.com/exec_dir/:/var/www/mySite.com/php-session/:/htdocs:/phptmp:/exec_dir:/php-session:/usr/share/php)
>   in
>   /htdocs/moustapha/Symfony2/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/preferences.php
>   line 15

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to the terminal? if so you should make sure that your web service user has access to write to the needed directories. I would recommend looking at this:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Specifically the section on permissions.